# Guideline to choose among horizontal bar chart and vertical bar chart (For mobile device)

Tags: android, charts, statistics

Currently, I were to implement a bar chart, to show dividend received from year 2000 till 2013 (as an example)

I was still puzzling, on whether I should go for horizontal bar chart or vertical bar chart?

[image]

[image]

My first approach is trying with vertical bar chart.

[image]

The year range (2000 till 2013) cannot fit into small screen width entirely. I need to have a view pager, so that user can swipe to view different year range. However, there is a shortcoming. User can only view 3 years data at one time.

I was thinking, if I can implement it as horizontal bar chart, user can view more years data at one time. But, is there any other shortcoming for horizontal bar chart?

**I was wondering, is there any guideline or reading I can refer to, so that I know which type of bar chart is more suitable for my case?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

horizontal bar chart for portrait layout 
and vertical bar chart forlandscape layout
[image]

Comment: The chart should be adaptable to best fit in the limited screen size of a mobile devices.